# What is the difference between "Array.fill(2)(new A)" and "val a=new A; Array.fill(2)(a)"?

Tags: class, scala, new-operator, cloning, scala-2.9

Minimal Working Example (Scala 2.9.2):

```
object Main extends App {
  class A {
    var a=0
  }
  val b = Array.fill(2)(new A)
  b(1).a = 9
  println(b(0).a) //prints 0
  println(b(1).a) //prints 9

  val a = new A
  val c = Array.fill(2)(a)
  c(1).a = 9
  println(c(0).a) //prints 9
  println(c(1).a) //prints 9
}
```

A related question is "Is it the same with imported Java classes?"
How can I workaround, if I need to fill an Array inside a function with copies of an instance passed as argument?
[Regarding identical copies, it was worth to me to check out the easy [cloning library](http://code.google.com/p/cloning/wiki/Usage).

Just adding the workaround to a function call, based on answers:

```
  class A {
    var a=0
  }

  def f(a: => A) {             // "=>" added
    val b = Array.fill(2)(a)
    b(1).a=9
    println(b(0).a) //prints 0
    println(b(1).a) //prints 9
  }

  f(new A)
```

Another way is to declare a function, not a value `def a = new A`:

```
object Main extends App {
  class A {
    var a=0
  }
  val b = Array.fill(2)(new A)
  b(1).a = 9
  println(b(0).a) //prints 0
  println(b(1).a) //prints 9

  def a = new A
  val c = Array.fill(2)(a)
  c(1).a = 9
  println(c(0).a) //prints 0
  println(c(1).a) //prints 9
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `fill` method is defined with it's second parameter as "call-by-name".  This means that the passed-in block is *re-evaluated* for every cell in the Array.  See in the definition that the type of `elem` is `=> T`, not simply `T`:

```
def fill[T: ClassManifest](n: Int)(elem: => T): Array[T]
```

So in your first version, the block `new A` is re-evaluated for each cell, meaning that each cell gets a fresh `A` object.  In the second version, `new A` is called only once, and that object is placed into every cell.

You can actually see this if you run on the REPL:

```
scala> val b = Array.fill(2)(new A)
b: Array[A] = Array(A@2049bed2, A@498edd8d)    // two different objects

scala> val c = Array.fill(2)(a)
c: Array[A] = Array(A@31e0c0b6, A@31e0c0b6)    // the same object repeated
```

Comment: Side note: `toString()` shows the hex code and not the memory address.

Answer (score 2):

Having a look at the signature of fill

```
def fill[T: ClassManifest](n: Int)(elem: => T)
```

So it gets a call-by-name argument, which means `new A` will be executed every time you process a cell in the array.

Answer (score 1):

One fills the array with a single instance of A, the other fills the array with a new instance of A.